# Oracle backend does not support timezone-aware datetimes when USE_TZ is False

Tags: django, oracle, datetime, timezone, cx-oracle

I am saving date-time value in oracle using Django. My model has `last_updated_at = DateTimeField()`.

This date-time value will be displayed by other application that is not developed in Django.

I set `last_updated_at` with date-time which is not in **UTC** but it's always saving it in UTC timezone.

When I set `USE_TZ = False` it gives error **Oracle backend does not support timezone-aware datetimes when USE_TZ is False**

I also tried `TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Karachi'` in `settings.py` but still date is saved in UTC.

Any who can help please??, Thanks

Comment: what is the data type of the column in the oracle table?

Comment: datetime is data type of columns. these are standard columns we use in oracle ERP. latupdate_date, creation_date.. etc.

Answer (score 1):

I found it's solution from Django documents. See following link for details

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#time-zone

In summary, in case when you are using database that is not managed by Django and other application are directly using that Database then you should set TIME_ZONE in DATABASES settings just like

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': 'XXX',
        'USER': 'XXX',
        'PASSWORD': 'XXX',
        'HOST': 'XX.XX.XX.XX',
        'PORT': 'XXXX',
        'TIME_ZONE': 'Asia/Karachi'
    }
}
```

Also set **USE_TZ=True**

Comment: It is specially true for database which do not support time zone like SQLite, MySQL, Oracle.. etc.

Comment: Setting **USE_TZ=True** was enough for me. I didn't need to add `'TIME_ZONE'`in DB config. I use MySql